# Baked chocolate cake type dessert with 'sticky' top

Tags: cake, chocolate, food-identification

I am in the UK and in my 60's.  My Mum used to make a cake in the oven that was heavy cake like at the bottom, but was still slightly sticky on top.

Can anyone tell me if they know of this and what it is called please?  She was given the recipe by a friend of hers.

Comment: I think you need to try to think of more detail: do you know any of the ingredients? Flavour? Colour and appearance? Cooking time? What it was served with? Typical size or depth? Texture or density? Area in the UK? Even small pieces of trivial information could help someone have a guess.

Comment: Spent ages looking through things like Mississippi Mud Pie and similar, but have come to the conclusion from pictures I have seen and recipes I have looked at, that it appears to be more like a Brownie.   As I did not help cook it, I don't know the ingredients, but it did taste like a VERY heavy cakey type recipe that was just sort of sticky on the top, but did not appear to taste very different.